# Check if UIDatePicker.date is nil in Swift

Tags: swift2, xcode7, uidatepicker

This must be obvious, but I just don't get it.

I'm trying to write a function where the values of a **UIDatePicker** and a **UIPickerView** (for seconds) need to be checked for nil (in case one of them is still spinning).
So I had:

```
let datePicker = view.viewWithTag(9) as! UIDatePicker

if datePicker.date != nil {

}
```

For which I get a **Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSDate' and 'NilLiteralConvertible**.

Comment: datepicker.date is always set because it is of type NSDate and not NSDate?
So if you want to check for spinning have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055688/detect-if-uidatepicker-is-rolling

Comment: Thank you! Should I delete the question?

Comment: dont know the best way to handle this. deleting is always bad, it removes information that might be needed...
i will just add my comment as an answer and then you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datepicker.date` is of type `NSDate`, not `NSDate?`. ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/date)) That's why you cannot check if it is `nil` because it is not an optional.

If you want see if it is still spinning refer to this question: [Detect if UIDatePicker is rolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5055688/1288394)